# How to delete a doc with id with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to delete a doc with id in mongoose. It executes the method but doesn't delete that doc in MongoDB Altas.
Note:Everthing is correct and also Passing id correctly in PostMan.

here is my controller :

```
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

exports.postPost = async (req, res) => {
try {
const post = await new Post({
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  title: req.body.title,
  desc: req.body.desc,
}).save();
console.log("Saved in db!");
return res.status(201).json({
  success: true,
  data: post,
});
 } catch (error) {
return res.status(500).json({
  success: false,
  message: "Server Error",
});
 }
};

exports.deletePost = async (req, res) => {
let postID = req.params.id;
await Post.deleteOne({ _id: postID }, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).json({
    message: "Something went wrong, please try again later.",
  });
} else {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Post Deleted",
    data: data,
  });
}
});
};
```

here is my posts route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
postPost,
deletePost,
  } = require("../controllers/posts_controller");

 router.route("/:id").delete(deletePost);
 router.route("/").post(postPost);

module.exports = router;
```

here is my postman :
[image]

here is my mongodb altas:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the **findOneAndDelete({_id:postId})** instead of deleteOne in posts controller
Or
use **findByIdAndDelete(postId)**  instead of deleteOne in posts controller

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.deletePost = async (req, res) => {
let postID = req.params.id;
await Post.findByIdAndDelete(postID, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).json({
    message: "Something went wrong, please try again later.",
  });
} else {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Post Deleted",
    data: data,
  });
}
});
};
```

Comment: Giving this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ff2fc8adcf1931350b3a7c8\n" at path "_id" for model "Posts"